# Heroku deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I'm following [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec%3amicroposts_resource) tutorial, and have followed the steps to deploying to `Heroku`.

When I open the application from `Heroku`, this is what I get:

> Heroku | Welcome to your new app!

Why isn't my application showing up?

**EDIT:** This is what I get when I run `heroku logs`:

```
$ heroku logs
←[36m2011-07-29T18:08:11+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Add-on add logging:basic by xyz@xyz.com
←[36m2011-07-29T18:08:11+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v1 created by xyz@xyz.com
←[36m2011-07-29T18:08:13+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Add-on update shared-database
←[36m2011-07-29T18:08:13+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v3 created by xyz@xyz.com
←[33m2011-07-29T18:08:45+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation started
←[36m2011-07-29T18:09:37+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy e04b0d1 by xyz@xyz.com
←[36m2011-07-29T18:09:37+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v4 created by xyz@xyz.com
←[32m2011-07-29T18:09:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
starting
←[33m2011-07-29T18:09:40+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
←[32m2011-07-29T18:09:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command
`thin -p 59785 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
←[32m2011-07-29T18:09:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Maximum connections set to 102
4
←[32m2011-07-29T18:09:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codena
me Crazy Delicious)
←[32m2011-07-29T18:09:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:59785, CT
RL+C to stop
←[32m2011-07-29T18:09:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 up
←[35m2011-07-29T18:10:08+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
 starting
←[35m2011-07-29T18:10:10+00:00 app[rake.1]:←[0m Awaiting client
←[35m2011-07-29T18:10:11+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m State changed from starting t
o up
←[35m2011-07-29T18:10:11+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m Process exited
←[35m2011-07-29T18:10:12+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m State changed from up to comp
lete
←[33m2011-07-29T18:13:55+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation started
←[36m2011-07-29T18:14:52+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy dbed18f by xyz@xyz.com
←[36m2011-07-29T18:14:52+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v5 created by xyz@xyz.com
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up to bounc
ing
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from bouncing to
 created
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
starting
←[33m2011-07-29T18:14:53+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with SIGTERM
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:54+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Stopping ...
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command
`thin -p 49961 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:58+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codena
me Crazy Delicious)
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:58+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Maximum connections set to 102
4
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:58+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:49961, CT
RL+C to stop
←[32m2011-07-29T18:14:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 up
←[35m2011-07-29T18:15:21+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m State changed from created to
 starting
←[35m2011-07-29T18:15:24+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m State changed from starting t
o up
←[35m2011-07-29T18:15:25+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m State changed from up to comp
lete
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:47+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:47+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:47+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/use
←[31m←[0m
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Processing by UsersController#i
ndex as HTML
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Err
or in 61ms
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (P
GError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m : SELECT "users".* FROM "users"):

←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/users_controlle
r.rb:5:in `index'
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[32m2011-07-29T19:18:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Idling
←[32m2011-07-29T19:18:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up to down
←[32m2011-07-29T19:18:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with SIGTERM
←[32m2011-07-29T19:18:58+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Stopping ...
←[32m2011-07-29T19:18:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited
←[35m2011-08-02T07:38:42+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
 starting
←[35m2011-08-02T07:38:44+00:00 app[rake.1]:←[0m Awaiting client
←[35m2011-08-02T07:38:45+00:00 app[rake.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `r
ake db:migrate`
←[35m2011-08-02T07:38:45+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m State changed from starting t
o up
←[35m2011-08-02T07:38:45+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m Process exited
←[35m2011-08-02T07:38:46+00:00 heroku[rake.1]:←[0m State changed from up to comp
lete
←[33m2011-08-02T07:58:10+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation started
←[36m2011-08-02T07:59:08+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy e5db406 by xyz@xyz.com
←[36m2011-08-02T07:59:08+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v6 created by xyz@xyz.com
←[33m2011-08-02T07:59:11+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
←[35m2011-08-02T07:59:44+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m State changed from created to
 starting
←[35m2011-08-02T07:59:46+00:00 app[rake.2]:←[0m Awaiting client
←[35m2011-08-02T07:59:46+00:00 app[rake.2]:←[0m Starting process with command `r
ake db:migrate`
←[35m2011-08-02T07:59:47+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m State changed from starting t
o up
←[35m2011-08-02T07:59:48+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m Process exited
←[35m2011-08-02T07:59:49+00:00 heroku[rake.2]:←[0m State changed from up to comp
lete
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Unidling
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from down to cre
ated
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to
starting
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command
`thin -p 12972 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:32+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codena
me Crazy Delicious)
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:32+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Maximum connections set to 102
4
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:32+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:12972, CT
RL+C to stop
←[32m2011-08-02T08:00:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to
 up
←[32m2011-08-02T09:01:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Idling
←[32m2011-08-02T09:01:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up to down
←[32m2011-08-02T09:01:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with SIGTERM
←[32m2011-08-02T09:01:46+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m >> Stopping ...
←[32m2011-08-02T09:01:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've created a heroku app but you haven't yet pushed it from your local machine to heroku.

Comment: @mark. I actually did, as I ran: 'git push heroku master'. Thanks

Comment: @Med-SWEng try this ' git add . ' and then this ' git commit -am "first commit" '. As Nicolas suggested, what does the ' heroku logs ' command print out?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting this page and not an error but it looks like you need to run your db migrations - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (P
GError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist.

Comment: Confirming what @mark said. This line in your log shows that the Users table does not exist. `[32m2011-07-29T18:17:48+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (P
GError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

From the logs it looks like you have not migrated your database, because it is looking for a table users. To migrate type this in 'heroku rake db:migrate VERSION=0' and then type 'heroku rake db:migrate'. Take a look here in heroku docs

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database

under the 'Common Issues Migrating to PostgreSQL' section. Also checkout this

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli

, for all the commands that you can run from terminal. Since you are using heroku, try and get your local database to also be postgresql, will solve some minor problems later. Remember every time that you push files to heroku, you will want to migrate database, if you have changes something in database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
heroku logs
```

to see what is currently happening on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing would be to start over. Go into the root of your app. Such as `myapp` and remove the git repo.

```
cd sites
cd myApp
git rm -r .git
```

Then log into Heroku and destroy your app in the CMS. After that create a new heroku rails app by going into your directory, creating a new repo, adding your directory, committing as master, creating a heroku app and then pushing to heroku.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'master'

heroku create
heroku rename myApp
git push heroku master
```

Then you will need to run your migrations.

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

And if you want to push data from your local machine to production you will want to use the taps gem but make sure you add that to your bundle.

```
gem 'taps'
```

And then run bundle again.

```
bundle
```

Then you can push your local data if need be.

```
heroku db:push
```

Answer (score 0):

Abit late, but i encountered this issue. I was missing foreman in my gemfile

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the railstutorial.org
comment out sqlite 3 (#gem 'sqlite3') in the Gemfile

then:

```
git add .

git commit -am "fix heroku"

git push heroku
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, delete your package.json then npm init. Delete your existing app in Heroku and push back the app with new package.json.